# Best Project Approach in Node JS

Tags: node.js, linux, windows, reactjs

I'm new to Node JS development. As an ASP.NET MVC developer, I normally use Repository Design Pattern where I have separate projects for Front-End and Database access in one solution. In addition, when creating a REST api, this can be added to the existing solution. So when publish, it api and front-end is separated by a different route.

I've just created a REST Service in Node JS and it's really simple and I like it. However, when it comes to Front-end I was looking at ReactJS, I've seen a blog (unfortunately, I can't find the link) where it separates the process between the REST service and react front end. I'm just wondering if this is a common design pattern in nodeJS using ReactJS. And if there's a benefit on doing this. Specially nowadays, Full Stack developers are a common thing. I can see the benefit of it from a maintenance stand point but I'm just wondering if there's a benefit in terms of server resources i.e. memory, cpu. Should the OS handle 1 vs 2 nodejs process? Will this differ from using linux vs windows?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. What do you mean *"separates the process"*? How does the front-end affect the server resources? Without the blog or a good summary of it, it's unclear what argument you're trying to support. In any event, *"best"* without specific evaluation criteria is inevitably opinion-based.

Comment: I'm still looking for the blog. But the way it was done, there's a process on the React front End and another process for the NodeJS REST Service which did CRUD to mongodb.

Comment: If you're talking about a dev server like create React app's, you shouldn't run that in production. Have a look at the setup I put together here: https://github.com/textbook/cyf-app-starter

Answer (score 0):

I see a huge benefit of separating the frontend from the backend so I would propose you to have your Node backend running in its own project and let's say a React solution running on its own. The React client can then consume that API together with other APIs later. By separating you have the benefit of scaling later.

Comment: OTOH that adds a lot of deployment complexity (dealing with e.g. CORS, service discovery) that you may never need. It's not that difficult to split out microservices later if it actually turns out to be necessary or helpful.

Comment: Will there be a CORS problem even if I'm hosting both projects on the same server?

Comment: @ReydanGatchalian yes, you'll have to deal with it; protocol, domain *and port* all have to match to avoid dealing with CORS

Comment: Depends if you think of CORS as a problem or security... :) But I agree, I use this structure for bigger projects and not small.

Answer (score 0):

If you've already built the REST service in node, you can access it via proxy in the React project's `package.json` by adding
    "proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:5001/"

It helps manage CORS issues.

Comment: That'll only work in local development, though; the CRA server isn't suitable for production use.